# How to get turtles run back and forth a coloured patch?

Tags: netlogo

I have a simple image as a map. I would like the turtles to start from the lighter grey colour and run to the darker patches for resources. How can I do that?

My Code

```
to setup-patches
  import-drawing "01.png"
  import-pcolors "01.png"
  ask patches [
    setup-house
    ;setup-resource
  ]
end

to setup-house
  create-turtles [setxy where pcolor = grey]
  set house? where pcolor = grey
end
```

The image is at https://i.stack.imgur.com/70q0s.png.

I can provide more details on request.

Comment: Sorry about my original question, I had started some work and I will post my work in a minute.

Comment: are you trying to create a house on each grey patch, or just on some of them?

Comment: The light grey patch is where the house is, and the darker one is where they get resources. The turtles will move back and forth between these two colored patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, a `patch` is actually a NetLogo term for one of the grid cells in the World. Your image suggests that the grey areas will cover multiple NetLogo patches each. The following code creates some random grey multi-patch areas and a house at one of the patches in one of the grey areas.

```
breed [houses house]

to testme
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-houses
end

to setup-patches
  ask n-of 3 patches
  [ set pcolor gray
    ask neighbors
    [ set pcolor gray
      ask neighbors
      [ set pcolor gray
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to setup-houses
  ask one-of patches with [pcolor = gray]
  [ sprout-houses 1
    [ set color red
    ]
  ]
end
```

Your question is too vague to properly answer, but hopefully this will get you on the right track. I suggest you redo the NetLogo tutorials and look at some of the models in the library included in the software to find pieces of code that do tasks you are going to need.

Comment: Thank you, it does the thing that I wanted. But seriously, I owe you a lot upon when I wasn't very clear about my question, and you still responded to my request.